# suma dentro de un array de valores repetidos

Tags: java, array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[5];
    int contador = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
        if (array[i] == 1){ 
            contador ++;
            System.out.println(contador);
        }
        else  {
            contador = 0;

        }
    }System.out.println("");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        contador = 0;
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

la compilación seria

ej 1 00100. Yo quiero que el programa me sume los números 1 que estén juntos ej 2 1 (suma los dos 1 que están juntos y separa el que esta solo)     11001(array).
ahora mismo lo que hace el código es esto si la array esta así 11101 el resultado que yo quiero que me de el contador es 3 1, el que me da es 123 1

Comment: Podrias explicarte mejor? no se entiende lo que quieres hacer, podrias dar un ejemplo del resultado que deseas? veo que estás generando un número al azar si este número que generas es igual que el anterior quieres sumarlo?

Comment: hola gracias por responder, si lo que tu dices es lo que quiero que haga el programa ejemplo que hace el programa  111     11001. ejemplo de lo que quiero que haga 21 11001. gracias .

Comment: Saludos @Arsenbasha, te recomiendo que modifiques tu pregunta dando un poco más de detalle de lo que necesitas ya que por ejemplo mencionas que se detecte el cero delante y detras **(¿Que acción se debe hacer cuando los detecta?)** , otro caso es que mencionas que si los numeros dos y 1 estan juntos deberian sumarse **(Pones de ejemplo 100100 y la salida 2111001 ¿De donde salieron los otros unos?)** posiblemente comprendí mal la entrada y salida que esperas, y eso es lo que seria bueno que expliques modificando tu post. Estoy seguro que si explicas los puntos que mencione te responderán.

Comment: A ver si entiendo. Quieres sumar el número anterior solo si los dos números(el actual y el anterior) son igual a `1`? de ser así  tu ejemplo de `111 11001` la salida seria `22101` y no `21 11001` correcto?

Comment: hola @centenond, tengo una array que me da aleatoriamente números del 0-1 , el tamaño de esta es de 5, lo que yo quiero es que si hay dos 1 los sume. ejemplo 2 1( esta seria la suma, el 2 porque están dos 1 juntos y después otro 1 porque esta al final del array )  11001(resultado del array).gracias

Comment: Lei varias veces tu pregunta, y tus ejemplos, y no me queda nada claro cual es la entrada y cual la salida. Por favor, deja bien claro, si entra 11001, cual queres que sea la salida. Tambien, explica que trata de hacer tu programa y donde es que no hace lo que vos queres que haga.

Comment: He editado tu pregunta para hacerla más clara. Ya que creo haber entendido lo que quieres hacer. También he dejado una respuesta.

Comment: @centenond se agradece la intención, pero debe ser el OP quién edite y esclarezca la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me ha costado un poco entender pero creo que ya entendí.

Mi idea es que inicies otro `array` llamemoslo `array2`

Mientras se generan los numeros del `array1` vas contando los `1` con el `contador`

Añadimos el `contador` al `array2` y reiniciamos el `contador` a `0` cuando se genere un numero que **no** sea `1` y el `contador` **no** es igual a `0`

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[]     array  = new int[5];
    ArrayList<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.println("Array:");
    int contador = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
        System.out.println(array[i]);

        // Verificamos si es el ultimo numero del array
        boolean esElUltimo = i == array.length-1;
        //si es 1 incrementamos el contador
        if (array[i] == 1)
            contador ++;
        //si no es 1 y el contador no es 0 O si es el ultimo y el contador no es 0, añadimos el contador al array 2, y reiniciamos el contador
        if(array[i] != 1 && contador != 0 || esElUltimo && contador != 0) {
            array2.add(contador);
            contador = 0;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Array2(Resultado):");
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(array2.get(i));
    }
}
```

Salida...

```
Array:
0
1
0
1
1
Array2(Resultado):
1
2
```